# Unable to parse to JSONARRAY

Tags: android, arrays, json

I get JSON response in my android application in which it contains an array which i parse to JSON in my code, it can't parse and the JSON looks fine

Code

```
JSONArray A=response.getJSONArray("Favs");
```

Server Response

```
{"Success":true,"FavFound":true,"Favs":"[{\"ID\":1,\"UserI\":1,\"LocName\":\"A7a\",\"Lat\":5.0,\"Lng\":5.0}]"}
```

Error

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"ID":1,"UserID":1,"LocName":"A7a","Lat":5.0,"Lng":5.0}] at Favs of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of "Favs" is a string. Because it is wrapped with quotations ""

Look carefully:

```
"Favs":"[{\"ID\":1,\"UserI\":1,\"LocName\":\"A7a\",\"Lat\":5.0,\"Lng\":5.0}]"
```

If it is a JSON Array it should look like this:

```
"Favs":[{"ID":1,"UserI":1,"LocName":"A7a","Lat":5.0,"Lng":5.0}]
```

with no quotations outside the brackets and no slash notations before those quotations inside too.

Answer (score 1):

"Favs" is string in your response.

Comment: String with a value of jsonarray ?